# Not Able see Service Appointment on FSL Mobile App

Tags: field-service-lightning, fieldservice

I have installed FSL mobile app and configured it. But when i login in, am not able to see any service appointment..It says "Looking good.There are no Service Appointment assigned to you for Today".
But i have Service appointment assigned.

Comment: any update on that.., I am facing the same issue